# GeoServer 2.18. Setting Min & Max Scales

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-css-module

I'm using CSS and wanted to know how to set the min and max scale for a given layer.  I see many solutions referencing SLD, but want to do this in CSS.  I really need help with the syntax.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt check the [CSS Styling Cookbook](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/css/cookbook/point.html#zoom-based-point) - simply you use the "magic" scale denominator variable (`@sd`) in a filter.

> ```
> * {
>    mark: symbol(circle);
>  }
>
>  :mark {
>    fill: #CC3300;
>  }
>
>  [@sd < 16M] {
>    mark-size: 12;
>  }
>
>  [@sd > 16M] [@sd < 32M] {
>    mark-size: 8;
>  }
>
>  [@sd > 32M] {
>    mark-size: 4;
>  }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  What is happening is that the layer is completely vanishing at a certain zoom out.  It is not necessarily even a large area, maybe the size of Massachusetts.  I cannot find any global settings or directives anywhere that may be the root cause.

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.